# Php get data from database in a custom structure

Tags: php, mysql

I have more then 100 records in the MySQL database. I have fetched them without any issue. But I want to show them in a different way like this

```
    -----------------------------------------------------
        first data here  |    second data here
-----------------------------------------------------
third data here | fourth data here | fifth data here
-----------------------------------------------------
sixth data here | seventh data here | eight data here
------------------------------------------------------
        ninth data here |  tenth data here  
------------------------------------------------------
 11th data here | 12th data here | 13th data here
 -----------------------------------------------------
 14th data here | 15th data here | 16th data here
 ----------------------------------------------------
    17th data here    |  18th data here
```

So you can see in the first row I have two columns only. In second I have 3 columns then in 3rd column I have 3 columns. Then again in the 4th row I have 2 columns again. So basically this goes like a loop. So can someone tell me how to get this kind of structure.
So far now I have got my code like this for getting data from database

```
<?php
  $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "username";
    $password = "password";
    $dbname = "myDB";

    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 

    $sql = "SELECT id, firstname, lastname FROM MyGuests";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        $i = 0;
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $i++;
            if( $i%2 == 0) {
                echo '<div class="1st-column">'. $row["id"]. " - Name: " . $row["firstname"]. " " . $row["lastname"].'</div>';
            }
            if ($i%3 ==0) {
                echo '<div class="2nd-column">'. $row["id"]. " - Name: " . $row["firstname"]. " " . $row["lastname"].'</div>';
            }
            if ($i%3 ==5) {
                echo '<div class="3rd-column">'. $row["id"]. " - Name: " . $row["firstname"]. " " . $row["lastname"].'</div>';
            }                

        }
    } else {
        echo "0 results";
    }
    $conn->close();
    ?>
```

So someone can kindly tell me how to get this working. Any help and suggestions will be really appreciable. Thanks

**Update**
I want my markup to goes like this

```
<div class="one-half">1st content</div>
<div class="one-half last">2nd content</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="one-third-content">3rd content</div>
<div class="one-third-content">4th content</div>
<div class="one-third-content last">5th content</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="one-third-content">6th content</div>
<div class="one-third-content">7th content</div>
<div class="one-third-content last">8th content</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="one-half">9th content</div>
<div class="one-half last">10th content</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
```

So can someone tell me how to achieve this with this kind of markup.

Comment: have you tried anything? any loops, or html, or css attempts?

Comment: You could use `%` modulus to tell if its the nth row, like `if( $i % 2 == 0 )`  modulus returns the remainder of division so  2 % 2 is 0 and is a even number row etc.  Like 4 % 2 == 0 ... 1 % 2 = 0.5

Comment: @maytham can you post your answer?

Answer (score 3):

Your pattern repeats every 8 results. Since you want the 1st 2 of each grouping to be offset, you would need `$i%8==1` and `$i%8==2`, or shortened to `in_array($i%8, array(1,2))`.

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    $i = 1;
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        if(in_array($i%8, array(1,2))) {
            $class = 'double'; // 2 wide
        }
        else {
            $class = 'triple'; // 3 wide
        }
        echo '<div class="'.$class.'">'. $row["id"]. " - Name: " . $row["firstname"]. " " . $row["lastname"].'</div>'; 
        $i++;          
    }
}
```

with the following CSS

```
<style>
    .double {float:left;width:50%;text-align:center;}   
    .triple {float:left;width:33%;text-align:center;}
</style>
```

---

**edit**
to get the format in your edit, your code would look something like this -

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    $i = 1;
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        // set class to one-half if position 1 or 2, else one-third-content
        $class = (in_array($i%8, array(1,2))) ? "one-half" : "one-third-content";

        // add last class if last in row, ie. 2, 5, or 8 (8th position is 0)
        $class .= (in_array($i%8, array(0,2,5))) ? " last" : "";

        // echo div
        echo '<div class="'.$class.'">'. $row["id"]. " - Name: " . $row["firstname"]. " " . $row["lastname"].'</div>'."\n";

        // echo div with clear class if last in row, ie. 2, 5, or 8 (8th position is 0)
        echo (in_array($i%8, array(0,2,5))) ? '<div class="clear"></div>'."\n": "";

        $i++;          
    }
}
```

Comment: that worked like charm. Just wanted to know something. How can I add class first to each row's first div through php code? Curious to know about that.

Comment: it would be done similar to `in_array($i%8, array(1,2)`. Since you want the 1st of each row, that is position `1`,`3`, and `6` in your group of 8. So you could do something like `if(in_array($i%8,array(1,3,6))){$class .= ' first';}`. This would append a class of `first` to each row's 1st `div`.

Comment: yes but this piece of code is breaking the structure of my requirment. It is showing the 1st rows 2nd column then 2nd rows one column one by one.

Comment: Not sure I follow what you are saying. So is adding the class `first` now making the results not 2-3-3? If so, that might be an issue with your `first` css. I would just be guessing without additional code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggestion in respect to Sean answer.

First of all, I have build the concept of splitting, this is to simplify thing before adaption, therefore I made a `for loop` to test and it works:

```
$lineBr1 = 0;
$lineBr2 = 0;
$lineBr3 = 0;

for ($i = 1; $i <= 100; $i ++)
{
    echo $i;

    $lineBr1 ++;
    $lineBr2 ++;
    $lineBr3 ++;

    if ($lineBr1 == 2) // 1st 2 names splitter
    {
        echo "<br />";
    }
    if ($lineBr2 == 5) // 2 + 3 = 5 (2nd 3 names splitter)
    {
        echo "<br />";
    }
    if ($lineBr3 == 8) // 2 + 3 + 3 = 8 (3rd 3 names splitter)
    {
        echo "<br />";
        $lineBr1 = 0;
        $lineBr2 = 0;
        $lineBr3 = 0;
    }
}
```

Since our `for loop` works we can implement it in your code, and here is what you need to add to your code:

```
$lineBr1 = 0;
$lineBr2 = 0;
$lineBr3 = 0;

if ($result->num_rows > 0)
{
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
        $lineBr1 ++;
        $lineBr2 ++;
        $lineBr3 ++;

        echo "<div style='float: left; width: 250px;'>" . $row["id"] . " - Name: " . $row["firstname"] . " " . $row["lastname"] . "</div>";

        if ($lineBr1 == 2)
            echo "<br />";
        if ($lineBr2 == 5)
            echo "<br />";
        if ($lineBr3 == 8)
        {
            echo "<br />";
            $lineBr1 = 0;
            $lineBr2 = 0;
            $lineBr3 = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Regarding design and layout, I leave that to your taste.

I am very sure this task can be done different ways, but this is what I have achieved.